# Multiple PHP If Statements inside HTML - Unexpected endif

Tags: php

Im trying to implement a second if statement inside a first statement, all of that inside HTML.
Should work like this:

- User logs in
- Login Script checks if information is missing (New User)
- If so, user needs to add it
- If not, just display "welcome back" (Known User)

  ```
        <?php if ($_SESSION['ID']): $log = 'Logout'; ?> <!-- If we have a session, login button becomes logout button-->

        <h1>You are logged in <?php echo $_SESSION['Name']; ?>!</h1>

            <?php if($_SESSION['locationcheck'] === False)?>  <!-- If login script says location is missing, form comes up to enter location-->

                <h2>Please complete by entering your location:</h2>
                    <!-- FORM TO ENTER LOCATION COMES UP-->

            <?php endif; ?> <!-- This endif is unexpected-->


  <?php else: $log = 'Login'; ?>     <!-- We dont have a session, display login button-->
        <h1>You are logged out!</h1>
          <div><?php echo '<a href='.$helper->getLoginUrl().'>Login with fb</a>';?></div>
  <?php endif ?>
  ```

The error I get is that the first endif is unexpected.

Comment: The endif is unexpected because the second If is missing a `:` to indicate the alternate syntax is being used.

Comment: Thanks, that's it!